# Do not see document properties I created

Tags: 2010, properties, copy

I moved a handful of documents out of a SharePoint library to a brand new library using the content and structure tool.  I added new documents to the new library and wanted to update the properties.  However the properties form shows the ORIGINAL properties and not what I added once the document were moved.  How do I edit this form?  The original properties are irrelevant for the new library.

Answer (score 0):

When you copied the documents, SharePoint probably copied the properties of the existing documents by adding columns to the library. Go to Library Settings and look to see if the extra, unwanted, columns are there. If they are really not needed, then delete them. Be aware that there is no undo for deleting columns.

Comment: I was able to remove the columns, but where do I add the new columns to the FORM I created for this library.  (I can see the columns in the library settings and they are available to edit if I use the "quick edit" feature but not the edit properties feature.

Comment: More info needed! What kind of form? InfoPath?

Comment: No I do not know how to do InfoPath.  just the "form" that automatically pops up when you hit edit properties... it doesn't have the new columns created in it - just the ones it carried over from the previous library.  I was able to delete it but now cannot add the new content.